# How to remotely call grant all permissions to an user in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin

I am trying to remotely to change permissions of my database user in MySQL.

Issue occur when I try to Grant permissions to my database user in PHPMyAdmin. 
when i execute this line: 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPass';`

Error Occur: `Access Denied to User _____ @ 'localhost' (using Password: Yes)`

Kindly Help Me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make sure that You are logged as root. Otherwise, it will always fail

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after you executed that line?

Sample:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user you're logged in as to execute that statement doesn't have "with grant option" privileges. That could be the root user or another privileged user.